# jQuery Mobile App - Fusion Tables Map click-to-call in infowindow isn't executing

Tags: iphone, jquery-mobile, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-markers, google-fusion-tables

Image Link of Issue - https://i.stack.imgur.com/3tE0i.jpg

When I open the fusion map within the safari browser on my phone and click on the number it gives me the option of calling that number, when I run it through the app however it does not.

I have put the following code in the fusion table

```
<a href="callto:12345678">+1 (555) 555-5555</a>
```

The 'tel:' function does not work either.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 0):

These are scrubbed from the info window template because they can cause security problems. You can take over the info window drawing if you want and populate it with anything you want, however.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. How do I take over the info window?

Comment: <div class='googft-info-window'>
<b>Text:</b> {Text}<br>
<b>Number:</b> {Number}<br>
<b>Location:</b> {Location}<br>
<b>Date:</b> {Date}
</div> How would i incorporate the callto: element into this? Thank you.

Comment: Take a look at this help page: https://developers.google.com/fusiontables/docs/samples/change_infowindow_content

Comment: Thanks for your help! Unfortunately I have tried for a few hours now and don't know enough about coding to get the number to call within the app which sucks because I have to submit it for my uni grad project tomorrow. Thank you again!